# A neural networks framework where I can set my own activation

Tags: neural-network

For my task, I need to implement a neural net with some arbitrary activation functions. To be more specific these activations are ReLUs, but all have a different first derivative.

I have my implementation of neural nets for that purpose, but it trains very poorly (to some threshold that is quite big) with ReLU for some reason.

So I need a framework that can help me quickly build NN with my ReLUs and apply it to some practical task like MNIST dataset. Language does not matter a lot, but I'd like to stick with C++\C\C#\Golang.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Java is alright. [DL4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/) easily supports custom activation functions by extending BaseActivationFunction.

```
public class Sample {
    static class MyActivationFunction extends BaseActivationFunction {
        @Override
        public INDArray getActivation( INDArray in, boolean training ) {
            Nd4j.getExecutioner().execAndReturn( new RectifedLinear( in ) );
            return in;
        }

        @Override
        public Pair<INDArray, INDArray> backprop( INDArray in, INDArray epsilon ) {
            INDArray dLdz = Nd4j.getExecutioner().execAndReturn( new RectifedLinear( in ).derivative() );
            dLdz.muli( epsilon );
            return new Pair<>( dLdz, null );
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "myrelu";
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .optimizationAlgo( OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT ).iterations( 1 )
            .learningRate( 0.0001 )
            .seed( 123 )
            .regularization( true )
            .l2( 0.005 )
            .weightInit( WeightInit.XAVIER )
            .updater( Updater.NESTEROVS )
            .activation( new MyActivationFunction() ) // << USE CUSTOM ACTIVATION FUNCTION
            .list()
            .layer( 0, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn( 768 ).nOut( 200 ).build() )
            .layer( 1, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn( 200 ).dropOut( 0.2 ).nOut( 200 ).build() )
            .layer( 2, new RnnOutputLayer.Builder( LossFunction.MCXENT ).activation( Activation.SOFTMAX ).nIn( 200 ).nOut( 10 ).build() )
            .pretrain( false ).backprop( true )
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears understandable and clear enough. So basicly (since only derivative is different) it comes down to writing a function that returns `INDArray` which is, i assume, an array of derivatives of all neurons in layer and then place it to `.execAndReturn (new RectifedLinear (in) .derivative () )` instead of given argument?

Comment: RectifedLinear accepts a cuttoff variable. I suspect you could just do: .execAndReturn (new RectifedLinear (in, 3)) (or another number) to change the slope.

Comment: It is not about a slope, but about the method of calculating derivative in x=0 (where it is undefined, strictly saying). I guess we can call it "a research"

Comment: I'd checkout the RectifiedLinear.java class - you could probably copy that and manipulate it as necessary - https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/6eb6081ed9c4a3b65d578b5cdb1c7eb4f8d960d5/nd4j-backends/nd4j-api-parent/nd4j-api/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ops/impl/transforms/RectifedLinear.java

Comment: Well, I've tried to make it work, but all for nothing. Turned out that Java classes are stubs and the real work is done by some c++ behind it. I ended up with "element-by-element" derivative calculation, and then puting them back into `in` array and assigned this array to `dldz`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python, then Keras would be the best way. It can use tensorflow backend which is in c++ and supports GPU
https://keras.io/

Answer (score 0):

In General for building a NeuralNet for detecting a number, you can follow these steps:

1. Datasets:

   - If you have your own dataset, check the sizes of labels and date to be suitable for the Neural Net.
   - If you don't have your own dataset, you can use prepared datasets like MNIST and others.
2. NeuralNetwork:

   - You can use `Tensorflow`In this [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) or `Keras`. It has a ready Example with good guide about code to run it and see the results.

It's ready and easy to run and see the result and Tensorflow guide explained the functions that used. so you can with a little search change your function that you need.